# Hadoop Home Path for Datanode

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm configuring a 3 node hadoop cluster in EC2.

For Namenode and Jobtracker:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop # Masternode
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
export HDFS_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib"
```

For Datanode, I attached additional EBS storage which is mounted on /vol,

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/vol/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
export HDFS_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib"
```

When I tried to run start-dfs.sh on Namenode I got following error,

```
data01.hdp-dev.XYZ.com: bash: line 0: cd: /usr/local/hadoop: No such file or directory
data01.hdp-dev.XYZ.com: bash: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: No such file or directory
```

Notice the Namenode trying to invoke hadoop from Datanode from wrong directory...

Any advice would help.